# Magento 2: Remove "active" class of search-bar on-click of mini cart?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

My problem is when I click on search button search bar open but when I click on mini cart search bar is still open, How to close search bar when I click on the mini cart, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below script on your website to make it work.

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("body .minicart-wrapper .showcart").on("click", function(){
                $('#search_mini_form').removeClass("active");
                $('#search_mini_form .label').removeClass("active");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Thank you its work for me @sumit